# Should I use WebP image format for image gallery?

Tags: html

So, I need to make a Gallery with lots of pictures, and different sizes. Problem is, that at some point it takes forever for phone to load images.

I found out about WebP format, which worked well, but turns out WebP is not supported by Firefox browser (YET?) which is a big problem.

So my question would be: Should I stay with JPG/PNG image formats, compress and resize them, so that they stay at 500kb to 2mb at max, or is it possible to make workaround for Firefox browser users?

My only idea was to make all images in JPG/PNG formats and make copy of them in WebP formats, after which, call {Onerror} function to load JPG/PNG image, but it made website even more slower since computer downloads all images from website...

> I have trouble figuring out, what would be best format/size for
>   pictures to make fast and reliable website with lots of images.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The WebP image format is supported by most modern browsers. However, it's not supported by IE, Safari, or iOS Safari.

[Check out the comparison chart for WebP image support.](https://caniuse.com/#feat=webp)

Personally, I use WebP images because my sites are small enough that I don't need to support the incompatible browsers, but if you want interoperability then you should use WebP images with fallbacks to JPG/PNG.

To address your final statement:

> I have trouble figuring out, what would be best format/size for pictures to make fast and reliable website with lots of images.

You may want to use some of the modern technologies, such as lazy loading or thumbnail compression so that images will load quickly all together. Then you can load a high-quality version when a user wants to look at a single photo.